# Dynamic updating AutoCompleteTextView popup the drop down again after item selected

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

I'm updating the AutoCompleteTextView dynamically and I'm facing two problems.

- when item selected there is a new onTextChanged event and as you can see in the code below there is a new request to get a new optional items so the onTextChanged event cause the AutoComplete show the drop down again! is there a clean way to solve it?!
- the results i get from the auto complete are from the previous adapter before I call notifyDataSetChange(), how can i make it happen?!

here is the code:

```
AutoCompleteTextView acCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete);
final ArrayAdapter<RMAutoComplete.ListItem> countriesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<RMAutoComplete.ListItem>(this.context,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
acCountry.setAdapter(countriesAdapter);
acCountry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() > 1)
            {
                new AsyncTask<String, Void, List<RMAutoComplete.ListItem>>(){

                    @Override
                    protected List<ListItem> doInBackground(String... params) {
                        List<ListItem> l = null;
                        try {
                            l = location.getCountryData(params[0]);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG,"error when getCountryData",e);
                        }
                        return l;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(List<ListItem> countries) {
                        countriesAdapter.clear();
                        if (countries != null)
                            for (ListItem listItem : countries) {
                                countriesAdapter.add(listItem);
                            }
                        countriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }.execute(s.toString());
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to achive the dynamic adapter what is need to do is to implement custom **Filter** class and override the performFiltering and publishResults methods.

In the performFiltering create new instance of **FilterResults** and initialize his values and count with the new items.. (this method works by default on a new thread!) something like this:

```
@Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults fr = null;
        if (constraint != null)
        {
            List<ListItem> list = getFilterdValues(constraint.toString());

            if (list != null)
            {
                fr = new FilterResults();
                fr.values = list;
                fr.count = list.size();
            }
        }
        return fr;
    }
```

and in the publishResults add the result to the adapter like this:

```
@Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
            FilterResults results) {
        AutoCompleteAdapter.this.clear();
        if (results != null)
        {
            if (results.values != null)
            {
                List<ListItem> items = (List<ListItem>) results.values;

                    for (ListItem listItem : items) {
                        AutoCompleteAdapter.this.add(listItem);
                    }

                if (items.size() > 0)
                {
                    AutoCompleteAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        AutoCompleteAdapter.this.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
```

also and importent is that you need to custom the adapter and overrirde getFilter with your own new custom Filter class like this:

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RMAutoComplete.ListItem> 
{


private CustomFilter _customFilter = null;

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    if (_customFilter == null)
        _customFilter = new CustomFilter();
    return _customFilter;
}


public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);

}

}
```

hope it was helpful for someone..

Comment: Cursor still blinks on the autocompleteTextview and the dropdown pops up even after selecting an item from dropdown. Please help:(